# ./configure excute success，then make failed with openssl in PHP7.1.4

Tags: openssl, php-7.1

I want to install php7,

> **first**,
>
> > `./configure --prefix=/usr/local/php --with-config-file-path=/etc --enable-fpm --with-fpm-user=nginx  --with-fpm-group=nginx --enable-inline-optimization --disable-debug --disable-rpath --enable-shared  --enable-soap --with-libxml-dir --with-xmlrpc --with-openssl --with-mcrypt --with-mhash --with-pcre-regex --with-sqlite3 --with-zlib --enable-bcmath --with-iconv --with-bz2 --enable-calendar --with-curl --with-cdb --enable-dom --enable-exif --enable-fileinfo --enable-filter --with-pcre-dir --enable-ftp --with-gd --with-openssl-dir --with-jpeg-dir --with-png-dir --with-zlib-dir  --with-freetype-dir --enable-gd-native-ttf --enable-gd-jis-conv --with-gettext --with-gmp --with-mhash --enable-json --enable-mbstring --enable-mbregex --enable-mbregex-backtrack --with-libmbfl --with-onig --enable-pdo --with-mysqli=mysqlnd --with-pdo-mysql=mysqlnd --with-zlib-dir --with-pdo-sqlite --with-readline --enable-session --enable-shmop --enable-simplexml --enable-sockets  --enable-sysvmsg --enable-sysvsem --enable-sysvshm --enable-wddx --with-libxml-dir --with-xsl --enable-zip --enable-mysqlnd-compression-support --with-pear --enable-opcache`

and it is successful~

> then, input make
>
> > `/opt/php7/php-7.1.4/ext/openssl/openssl.c:4103: undefined reference to`DSA_set0_pqg'
> >     /opt/php7/php-7.1.4/ext/openssl/openssl.c:4110: undefined reference to `DSA_set0_key'
> >     /opt/php7/php-7.1.4/ext/openssl/openssl.c:4122: undefined reference to`DSA_get0_key'
> >     /opt/php7/php-7.1.4/ext/openssl/openssl.c:4123: undefined reference to `BN_is_zero'
> >     ext/openssl/.libs/openssl.o: In function`php_openssl_pkey_init_dh':
> >     /opt/php7/php-7.1.4/ext/openssl/openssl.c:4180: undefined reference to `DH_set0_pqg'
> >     ext/openssl/.libs/openssl.o: In function`php_openssl_dh_pub_from_priv':
> >     /opt/php7/php-7.1.4/ext/openssl/openssl.c:4157: undefined reference to `BN_with_flags'
> >     ext/openssl/.libs/openssl.o: In function`php_openssl_pkey_init_dh':
> >     /opt/php7/php-7.1.4/ext/openssl/openssl.c:4194: undefined reference to `DH_set0_key'
> >     /opt/php7/php-7.1.4/ext/openssl/openssl.c:4187: undefined reference to`DH_set0_key'
> >     ext/openssl/.libs/xp_ssl.o: In function `sk_X509_num':
> >     /usr/local/include/openssl/x509.h:97: undefined reference to`OPENSSL_sk_num'
> >     ext/openssl/.libs/xp_ssl.o: In function `sk_X509_value':
> >     /usr/local/include/openssl/x509.h:97: undefined reference to`OPENSSL_sk_value'
> >     ext/openssl/.libs/xp_ssl.o: In function `sk_X509_num':
> >     /usr/local/include/openssl/x509.h:97: undefined reference to`OPENSSL_sk_num'
> >     ext/openssl/.libs/xp_ssl.o: In function `enable_server_sni':
> >     /opt/php7/php-7.1.4/ext/openssl/xp_ssl.c:1359: undefined reference to`TLS_server_method'
> >     ext/openssl/.libs/xp_ssl.o: In function `php_openssl_setup_crypto':
> >     /opt/php7/php-7.1.4/ext/openssl/xp_ssl.c:1512: undefined reference to`TLS_client_method'
> >     /opt/php7/php-7.1.4/ext/openssl/xp_ssl.c:1579: undefined reference to `SSL_CTX_set_alpn_select_cb'
> >     /opt/php7/php-7.1.4/ext/openssl/xp_ssl.c:1594: undefined reference to`SSL_CTX_set_options'
> >     ext/openssl/.libs/xp_ssl.o: In function `set_server_specific_opts':
> >     /opt/php7/php-7.1.4/ext/openssl/xp_ssl.c:1241: undefined reference to`SSL_CTX_get_options'
> >     /opt/php7/php-7.1.4/ext/openssl/xp_ssl.c:1268: undefined reference to `SSL_CTX_set_options'
> >     ext/openssl/.libs/xp_ssl.o: In function`php_openssl_setup_crypto':
> >     /opt/php7/php-7.1.4/ext/openssl/xp_ssl.c:1512: undefined reference to `TLS_server_method'
> >     /opt/php7/php-7.1.4/ext/openssl/xp_ssl.c:1574: undefined reference to`SSL_CTX_set_alpn_protos'
> >     ext/openssl/.libs/xp_ssl.o: In function `php_openssl_sockop_set_option':
> >     /opt/php7/php-7.1.4/ext/openssl/xp_ssl.c:2296: undefined reference to`SSL_get0_alpn_selected'
> >     ext/openssl/.libs/xp_ssl.o: In function `sk_GENERAL_NAME_num':
> >     /usr/local/include/openssl/x509v3.h:165: undefined reference to`OPENSSL_sk_num'
> >     ext/openssl/.libs/xp_ssl.o: In function `sk_GENERAL_NAME_value':
> >     /usr/local/include/openssl/x509v3.h:165: undefined reference to`OPENSSL_sk_value'
> >     ext/ftp/.libs/php_ftp.o: In function `zm_startup_ftp':
> >     /opt/php7/php-7.1.4/ext/ftp/php_ftp.c:313: undefined reference to`OPENSSL_init_ssl'
> >     /opt/php7/php-7.1.4/ext/ftp/php_ftp.c:314: undefined reference to `OPENSSL_init_crypto'
> >     /opt/php7/php-7.1.4/ext/ftp/php_ftp.c:315: undefined reference to`OPENSSL_init_crypto'
> >     /opt/php7/php-7.1.4/ext/ftp/php_ftp.c:316: undefined reference to `OPENSSL_init_crypto'
> >     /opt/php7/php-7.1.4/ext/ftp/php_ftp.c:318: undefined reference to`OPENSSL_init_ssl'
> >     ext/ftp/.libs/ftp.o: In function `ftp_login':
> >     /opt/php7/php-7.1.4/ext/ftp/ftp.c:283: undefined reference to`TLS_client_method'
> >     /opt/php7/php-7.1.4/ext/ftp/ftp.c:292: undefined reference to `SSL_CTX_set_options'
> >     ext/phar/.libs/util.o: In function`phar_verify_signature':
> >     /opt/php7/php-7.1.4/ext/phar/util.c:1563: undefined reference to `EVP_MD_CTX_new'
> >     /opt/php7/php-7.1.4/ext/phar/util.c:1586: undefined reference to`EVP_MD_CTX_free'
> >     /opt/php7/php-7.1.4/ext/phar/util.c:1595: undefined reference to `EVP_MD_CTX_free'
> >     ext/phar/.libs/util.o: In function`phar_create_signature':
> >     /opt/php7/php-7.1.4/ext/phar/util.c:1860: undefined reference to `EVP_MD_CTX_new'
> >     /opt/php7/php-7.1.4/ext/phar/util.c:1892: undefined reference to`EVP_MD_CTX_free'
> >     collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
> >     make: *** [sapi/cli/php] Error 1
> >     `

so,i need you help,thank you!

Comment: Many Autotools projects use `--with-openssl=/usr/local/ssl` or similar. What does the following output: `./configure --help | egrep -i '(tls|ssl|openssl)'`.